# How can I optimize my Firebird SQL query?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

Database: Firebird 3.0

This query is used to select records that fit a specific condition, in order to detect which `DEVICEID`'s have bigger `LAST_TICK`'s than what the `DEVICEID={INTEGER VALUE}` knows of others `DEVICEID`'s

Here is the SQL query:

```
select 
    a.TABELA, 
    a.DEVICEID,
    (select LAST_TICK from KNOWLEDGE b where b.DEVICEID={INTEGER VALUE} and b.CROSSID=a.DEVICEID and b.TABELA=a.TABELA) as MEU_TICK,
    max(LAST_TICK) as MAX_TICK 
from 
    KNOWLEDGE a 
where 
    a.DEVICEID=a.CROSSID 
group by
    a.TABELA, a.DEVICEID 
having 
    max(LAST_TICK) > (select LAST_TICK from KNOWLEDGE b where b.DEVICEID={INTEGER VALUE} and b.CROSSID=a.DEVICEID and b.TABELA=a.TABELA) 
order by 
    a.TABELA
```

Performance Statistics with only 11 records;

```
Plan
PLAN (B INDEX (PK_KNOWLEDGE))
PLAN (B INDEX (PK_KNOWLEDGE))
PLAN SORT (A NATURAL)

------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 0ms
Execute time = 0ms
Current memory = 36.473.632
Max memory = 36.729.200
Memory buffers = 2.048
Reads from disk to cache = 0
Writes from cache to disk = 0
Fetches from cache = 65

Select Expression
-> Singularity Check
    -> Filter
        -> Table "KNOWLEDGE" as "B" Access By ID
            -> Bitmap
                -> Index "PK_KNOWLEDGE" Unique Scan
Select Expression
-> Singularity Check
    -> Filter
        -> Table "KNOWLEDGE" as "B" Access By ID
            -> Bitmap
                -> Index "PK_KNOWLEDGE" Unique Scan
Select Expression
-> Filter
    -> Aggregate
        -> Sort (record length: 214, key length: 176)
            -> Filter
                -> Table "KNOWLEDGE" as "A" Full Scan
```

*** EDIT 1:
DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE KNOWLEDGE (
DEVICEID   "INTEGER" NOT NULL /* "INTEGER" = INTEGER */,
TABELA     VARCHAR40 NOT NULL /* VARCHAR40 = VARCHAR(40) */,
CROSSID    "INTEGER" NOT NULL /* "INTEGER" = INTEGER */,
LAST_TICK  "INTEGER" NOT NULL /* "INTEGER" = INTEGER */
);
ALTER TABLE KNOWLEDGE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_KNOWLEDGE PRIMARY KEY (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID);
CREATE INDEX KNOWLEDGE_IDX1 ON KNOWLEDGE (TABELA);
CREATE INDEX KNOWLEDGE_IDX2 ON KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, CROSSID);
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 4, 11);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 5, 47);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 6, 118);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (4, 'PESSOAS', 12, 5);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 4, 11);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 5, 47);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 6, 118);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (5, 'PESSOAS', 12, 5);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 4, 11);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 5, 47);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 6, 118);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (6, 'PESSOAS', 12, 5);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 4, 11);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 5, 47);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 6, 118);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (7, 'PESSOAS', 12, 5);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 4, 11);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 5, 47);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 6, 118);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (8, 'PESSOAS', 12, 5);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 4, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 5, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 6, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (9, 'PESSOAS', 12, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 4, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 5, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 6, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (10, 'PESSOAS', 12, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 4, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 5, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 6, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (11, 'PESSOAS', 12, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 4, 11);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 5, 47);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 6, 118);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 7, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 8, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGE (DEVICEID, TABELA, CROSSID, LAST_TICK)
           VALUES (12, 'PESSOAS', 12, 10);

COMMIT WORK;
```

Details of the logic:

Its used in data syncronization algorithm. This knowledge table holds the knowledge (Last Update Tick) from every device registered in the system, and its stored in the server. Client Devices connect to server and send updated records, and the server updates its knowledge table to reflect those changes. Then other client devices connect to server to get those changes and update their local database.

The logic of knowledge table is like this:

D-Hey server, i'm device 4, and i need to know if there is anything new for me?

S- K, hold on, let me check. Hey database server, get me all the records from the knowledge table that the DEVICEID's LAST_TICK is HIGHER than my own Knowledge of it (CROSSID=DEVICEID), also put in that query the device own knowledge so its easier for the server to build the query for those records.

DB- Sure, here is the list

S- Nice, now get me all those records from these tables that the update_tick is higher than device 4 knowledge.

Db- yup, there it is.

S- hey device, get those records and update it

d- np, done. thanks man..

With the test data provided above, the result should be a single row with the values, no matter what device id we are providing in {INTEGER VALUE}:
{ TABELA: "PESSOAS", DEVICEID: 12, MEU_TICK: 5, MAX_TICK: 12}

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Please provide DDL (including indexes) and sample data, would this query produce a single record, or can it have multiple results?

Comment: Oops, sorry, adding DDL and Sample records to the question. Also, the query produces multiple records results.

Comment: When I run the query, the result has `MAX_TICK=10`, not 12, also using deviceid 9, 10, 11 results in 4 rows, not just 1.

Comment: yes yes, my bad again.. its 10.. about devices 9,10 and 11 4 rows result, its because they haven't been sync'ed before me extracting the data from the table...

Comment: Why do you need condition `b.TABELA=a.TABELA` ? It does not seem to fit "what device A knows about device B" legend. Also why don't you include `b.CROSSID<>b.DEVICEID` filter ?

Comment: `Hey server, i'm device 4, and i need to know if there is anything new for me?` which IMHO means "is there any data concerning device 4 that it did not fetched last time". Expecting last check time stored as `LAST_TICK WHERE DEVICEID=4 AND  CROSSID=4` (undocumented column TABELA being excluded)

Comment: Then all the knowledge (rows) accumulated after the said last check seems to be (again, skipping undocumented TABELA column) `SELECT a.* from KNOWLEDGE a, KNOWLEDGE b WHERE b.DEVICEID=4 and b.DEVICEID=b.CROSSID and b.DEVICEID=a.CROSSID and b.DEVICEID<>a.DEVICEID and a.LASTTICK>b.LASTTICK` - such a query seems to be more straightforward. And if you would add an index on (LASTTICK, DEVICEID) it probably would be able to use it.

Comment: b.TABELA=a.TABELA its because we are searching for updates for that specific table.

Comment: I'm gonna try your suggestion later, than i'll come back here to tell the results. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.. i've made a few changes to your suggestions: 
  SELECT a.TABELA, a.DEVICEID, b.LAST_TICK as MEU_TICK, a.LAST_TICK as MAX_TICK from KNOWLEDGE a, KNOWLEDGE b WHERE b.TABELA=a.TABELA and b.CROSSID=a.DEVICEID and b.DEVICEID<>a.DEVICEID and a.DEVICEID=a.CROSSID and a.LAST_TICK>b.LAST_TICK and b.DEVICEID=4 , but with the same logic in mind. The result is: its fetching the hard drive half the times it was fetching with the other queries!! amazing suggestion!! thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple change that might improve performance, is changing

```
group by
    a.TABELA, a.DEVICEID
```

to

```
group by
    a.DEVICEID, a.TABELA
```

This will allow the optimizer to use `PK_KNOWLEDGE` for the sort necessary for aggregation.

A further optimization may be achieved by rewriting your query to:

```
with max_tick as (
    select 
       TABELA,
       DEVICEID,
       MAX(LAST_TICK) as MAX_TICK
    from KNOWLEDGE
    where DEVICEID = CROSSID
    group by DEVICEID, TABELA
)
select 
   a.TABELA,
   a.DEVICEID,
   a.MAX_TICK,
   b.LAST_TICK AS MEU_TICK
from max_tick a
inner join KNOWLEDGE b 
   on a.DEVICEID = b.CROSSID AND a.TABELA = b.TABELA and a.MAX_TICK > b.LAST_TICK
where b.DEVICEID = {INTEGER VALUE}
order by a.TABELA
```

But I'm not 100% sure if this query is equivalent, as your sample data doesn't provide enough variation to test this out.

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm going to test your suggestion and i come back later to tell you if its right and improved the performance

Comment: Ok. your query results appear to be correct on my tests.. I've performed a live test of your query on my software in asp.net core api, and here are the results (10 runs each query): My query avg 22.9ms, Changing the group by order, avg 25.1ms, And your full query avg 24.7ms. But, with your suggestions i get 0 non-indexed reads, which should out-perform my query as the knowledge table expands! I'm going to mark it as accepted because it has pottential

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cte like this:

```
With cte_base AS (
select distinct LAST_TICK 
from KNOWLEDGE b 
where b.DEVICEID={INTEGER VALUE} and b.CROSSID=a.DEVICEID 
and b.TABELA=a.TABELA
)

select 
    a.TABELA, 
    a.DEVICEID,
    cte_base.LAST_TICK as MEU_TICK,
    max(LAST_TICK) as MAX_TICK 
from 
    KNOWLEDGE a 
where 
    a.DEVICEID=a.CROSSID 
group by
    a.TABELA, a.DEVICEID 
having 
    max(LAST_TICK) > (cte_base.LAST_TICK) 
order by 
    a.TABELA
```

Comment: not working on firebird 3.0.. Column unknown.
CTE_BASE.LAST_TICK

Comment: replaced cte_base.last_tick with (select LAST_TICK from cte_base) and it worked

Comment: ok, tested it out, and the results are exactly the same, in indexed, non-indexed reads and fetches.